# Content-based filtering recommendation system for a group

Tags: clustering, recommender-system

Is there any example of content-based filtering recommendation for a group of observations? For example, user can choose a group of 10 movies they like the most, and the recommendation engine will return a list of movies that are most similar to the 10 movies they have chosen.

For a single observation I know we will calculate the distance between the single observation and the rest of the data, but for this group scenario, what would be the best way to implement it?